# Is there a way to get the row number at the insertion point of a Tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to change the color of text in a text widget similar to how a VS code changes the code colors:

Like this:

[image]

To do this I have a Text widget and I have a function `handleCodeEditor` bound to `<KeyRelease>` that will split the text widget's contents by row and then conditionally modify text colors. To make the process less exhaustive I would like to only modify the current row, but I am not aware of any method that would give me the row number.

Any ideas?

Comment: `self.codeEditor.index('insert')` will give you the insertion point location, as a string in *line.column* format.

Comment: In addition, note that *line* starts from 1 while *column* starts from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def getrow(event):
    index = textbox.index(INSERT)
    row = index.split(".")[0]
    print(row)

root = Tk()
textbox = Text(root)
textbox.bind("<KeyRelease>",getrow)
textbox.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This function will print the current line number whenever a key is released.
Hope this is what you're after.